# Getting "Conflicting overloads" for every function in one Kotlin file whenever I change it

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

For one Kotlin file in my project, almost every time I make changes to it and rebuild, I get "Conflicting overload" messages for every function. There aren't two conflicting functions; each error message lists exactly the same function twice. If I do a clean build, it builds fine.

> e: ContentApi.kt: (220, 1): Conflicting overloads: 
>   public fun loadExclusions(assetIds: List): Unit defined in com.foo.bar in file ContentApi.kt, 
>   public fun loadExclusions(assetIds: List): Unit defined in com.foo.bar in file ContentApi.kt

Changes to other Kotlin files don't produce the same problem. I can create a function in another Kotlin file, build with no trouble, then cut and paste it into this file, and boom.

Has anyone else seen something like this? My best guess is that it's some kind of bug with the compiled code cache where the newly compiled code doesn't replace the previous version, so they conflict with each other.

Android Studio/Gradle version 3.2 RC 3
Kotlin version 1.2.61

Comment: This looks like an incremental compilation bug, indeed. Does the problem persist if you upgrade to Kotlin 1.2.70 (the latest released version)?

Comment: I'll try it. It's definitely existed through a few Kotlin version updates, though I can't say exactly when it started.

Comment: I recently had this issue, after I pulled from a remote repo an updated version of my gradle project. I deleted the 'build' folder and rebuilt the project, and that cleared the error.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I can't recall what resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

This is normally happening when you have two functions with the same names but different annotations.

For example:

```kotlin
    @PrePersist
    public fun loadExclusions(assetIds: List) {
    }
    
    @PreUpdate
    public fun loadExclusions(assetIds: List) {
    }
```

Comment: Good thought, but there's only one function with that name. It seems to have gone away, but I can't say why. I have updated Android Studio, so that may have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and the problem was that I have changed package from main folder to location like debugger suggested on the beginning (before I changed all locations). When I left original package inside it was ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the package import line as well. It will be fixed for me when
I have updated the package import line properly with the correct package name.

Answer (score 0):

I head the same issue when building with `mvn package` but `mvn clean package` helped.

It may happen when someone rename a class, the previous compiled version will remain in target/classes and cause "Conflicting overload".